# Is it possible to label diagonal objects with bounding boxes?

Tags: annotations, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box, yolov5

I'm labelling objects for object detection with YOLOv5 and tried using makesense.ai, labelImg,... for that. It works fine with horizontal/vertical objects, but I do have some vertical ones in my dataset.
Is there a way for diagonal Bounding Boxes? Or is there any other way for labelling diagonal objects for improving performance of my model?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your bounding box will be squared or rectangular. For instance, the image below contains a small crack with a diagonal shape (red box). Unfortunately, YOLOv5 does not support other kinds of bounding boxes yet.

[image]